# Redirect base URL to wp/index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I open www.fimos.my, it should redirect me to www.fimos.my/wp/index.php, but I cannot get this to work correctly, this is what my htacess file looks like:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

 # END WordPress

 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maznia\.my$ [OR]
 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.maznia\.my$ [OR]
 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.fimos\.my$
 #RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/fimos.my\/wp\/index\.php" [R=301,L]

 #FORCE www
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fimos.my [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://fimos.my/wp/index.php" [L,R=301]
```

This show the error cannot find the file in cpanel, they direct to link fimos.my/wp/index only.. there aren't to fimos.my/wp/index.php
This is my question:

> 1. How to redirect to www.fimos.my/wp/index.php?

Comment: You say you wan't to redirect to that website, but where do you wanna redirect from?

Comment: you try go to this link http://www.fimos.my/wp/index.php

Comment: if you go to this link fimos.my you couldn't direct.. how I can set the htaccess file?

Comment: Still not sure what you are asking, when I go to fimos.my/wp/index.php, it redirects to http://fimos.my/wp/, when I go to http://fimos.my/wp/ it loads the website.

Comment: not like this.. u try fimos.my only.. if i want to enter fimos.my should be redirect link to fimos.my/wp/index.php